# Using images in XSLT for-each

Tags: xml

I am new to XML/ XSLT and am trying to display a table with data about people, including a flag with their country in. However, when I do this I just get the first image repeated in every row. Could anyone please help me to get a different flag shown in each row?

This is the format of my XML:

```
<person>  
            <firstname>Joe</firstname>
            <lastname>Bloggs</lastname>
              <picture src="/images/gb.png"/>
          </person>
```

This is my XSLT:

```
    <table class="table-striped">
     <tr>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Flag</th>
     </tr>

     <xsl:for-each select="person">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="firstname"/><xsl:value-of select="lastname"/></td>
         <td><img src="{/person/picture/@src}" /></td>
         </tr>
       </xsl:for-each>
   </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
<img src="{/person/picture/@src}" />
```

you are referring to an absolute path, but in your `xsl:for-each` you have already set your context node to `information/person`. So change your XPath to a relative (to the context node `person`) path like

```
<img src="{picture/@src}" />
```

This should take into account the context of the `xsl:for-each`.